# writing SQL Query with multiple else and where statements

Tags: sql

I have two tables table a and table b. 
**Table A has**

1. SystemName
2. Mem1
3. Mem2
4. GBL_Mem

**TABLE B has**

1. SystemName
2. OS

The output required is 3 columns
Systemname    OS and  GBL_mem

GBL_mem data should match two formulas

1. if os=NT avg of GBL_mem
2. if os<>NT avg of mem1 + avg of mem2

Help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Please edit the question to explain whether table A has strictly one or possibly multiple entries for each SystemName

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is basically a `join` and `group by`, with some conditional logic:

```
select a.systemname, b.os,
       (case when b.os = 'NT' then avg(a.GBL_Mem)
             else avg(a.mem1) + avg(a.mem2)
        end) as new_col
from a join
     b
     on a.systemname = b.systemname
group by a.systemname, b.os;
```